# Calculated Mean Squared Error with dataframe of residuals with grouping in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, mse

So I have a data frame of residuals as such:

```
ID    A    B    C     D 
1    .2 23.3  2.3  4.32
2   2.3  2.4    0     1
3  23.3  1.3   23  3.44
2  34.2   33 56.5  76.5
1   0.3 76.4  3.2  78.5
```

*There are about 200 variables

How would I calculate Mean Squared Error (MSE) using this by `ID`?

So basically, the MSE for each individual `ID` is the goal.

Comment: Do you want to calculate the MSE for each colum per individual, so the MSE for column A, and another MSE for column B or do you want to calculate an overall MSE, so per ID, but across all columns? Please explain. Also explain how exactly you want to calculate the MSE as there are different formula in different contexts.

Comment: Overall MSE , per ID. The MSE formular of SUM((X - Xi)^2) @deschen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
df_example %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarize(across(everything(), ~sum(.x^2)/n()))
```

which gives:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 5
     ID       A       B       C      D
  <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1   0.065 3190.      7.76 3090. 
2     2 587.     547.   1596.   2927. 
3     3 543.       1.69  529      11.8
```

Note that this gives different results compared to @Bruno's solution. It does give the same results, though, as Neeraj's solution.

I understand the TO in a way that his input already are the residuals in which case I only need to square each of them, create the sum per ID (and for each column) and divide by the observations per ID.

One example for column "A" and ID 2:

- Residuals are 2.3 and 34.2
- Squared residuals are 5.29 and 1169.64
- Sum of squared residuals is 1174.93
- MSE is sum of squared residuals divided by 2 = 587.465

Is that correct?

Comment: that is correct, we would need to addition of that step

Comment: So is the result above correct or not? If so it woudl be great if you could mark one of tehe correct answer as teh accepted one.

Answer (score 0):

The mean squared error for residuals is simply defined as:

[image: MSE for residuals]

To get MSE for each column you can simply use `apply` function in R:

```
df <- matrix(runif(100), ncol = 10) #dummy data

#generating ID in first column
set.seed(123)
df <- cbind(sample(1:3, 10, replace = TRUE), df)

mse <- aggregate(df[, 2:ncol(df)], by = list(df[, 1]), FUN = function(x) 1/length(x) * sum(x ** 2))
```

Comment: Ok, I understood your problem.

Comment: You need to do `aggregate(.~ID, df, function(x) mean(x^2))`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this is what I would do

```r
library(tidyverse)

df_example <- tibble::tribble(
  ~ID,   ~A,   ~B,   ~C,   ~D,
   1L,  0.2, 23.3,  2.3, 4.32,
   2L,  2.3,  2.4,    0,    1,
   3L, 23.3,  1.3,   23, 3.44,
   2L, 34.2,   33, 56.5, 76.5,
   1L,  0.3, 76.4,  3.2, 78.5
  )

df_example %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(lenght_vector = c_across(cols = c(A:D)) %>% length(),
            sum_vector = c_across(cols = c(A:D)) %>% sum(),
            mean_error = sum_vector/lenght_vector,
            MSE = mean_error %>% sqrt())
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>      ID lenght_vector sum_vector mean_error   MSE
#>   <int>         <int>      <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1             8      189.        23.6  4.85
#> 2     2             8      206.        25.7  5.07
#> 3     3             4       51.0       12.8  3.57
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>